# Slow iterating on fast computer

Tags: python

I have a dataset of house attributes including the areas of parts of the houses, for example, attribute 'WoodDeckSF' indicates the area of the wood decking. A value of zero indicates there is no decking.
I wanted to create an extra column for each area attribute containing binary values: decking or no decking.
I used the following script:

```py
#Create a Floors column based on the 2ndFlrSF attribute
df_full['Floors'] = ''
for row in range(0,2919):
    if df_full['2ndFlrSF'][row] == 0:
        df_full['Floors'][row] = 1
    else:
        df_full['Floors'][row] = 2
del row
df_full['Basement'] = ''
for row in range(0,2919):
    if df_full['BsmtFinSF1'][row] == 0:
        df_full['Floors'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['Floors'][row] = 1
del row
df_full['WoodDeck'] = ''
for row in range(0,2919):
    if df_full['WoodDeckSF'][row] == 0:
        df_full['WoodDeck'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['WoodDeck'][row] = 1
del row
df_full['EnPorch'] = ''
for row in range(0,2919):
    if df_full['EnclosedPorch'][row] == 0:
        df_full['EnPorch'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['EnPorch'][row] = 1
del row
df_full['OpPorch'] = ''
for row in range(0,2919):
    if df_full['OpenPorchSF'][row] == 0:
        df_full['OpPorch'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['OpPorch'][row] = 1
del row
df_full['Pool'] = ''
for row in range(0,2919):
    if df_full['PoolArea'][row] == 0:
        df_full['Pool'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['Pool'][row] = 1
del row
df_full['Garage'] = ''
for row in range(0,2919):
    if df_full['GarageArea'][row] == 0:
        df_full['Garage'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['Garage'][row] = 1
del row
```

This does exactly what I wanted (I'm sure it could be done better). When I run it on my laptop it executes in about 5 seconds but when I run it on my more powerful desktop it takes around 20+ minutes.
What could be causing it to go so slow?

Comment: I'm sure all those `del row` calls aren't helping.

Comment: Are you using the same version of Python on both machines? `range(0, 2919)` does two very different things in Python 2 and Python 3.

Comment: Python 3.6 on both. I also tried it without deleting the row value but that made no difference

Answer (score 1):

Combine to make it a single loop since it's the same loop every time.

```py
#Create a Floors column based on the 2ndFlrSF attribute
df_full['Floors'] = ''
df_full['Basement'] = ''
df_full['WoodDeck'] = ''
df_full['EnPorch'] = ''
df_full['OpPorch'] = ''
df_full['Pool'] = ''
df_full['Garage'] = ''

for row in range(0,2919):
    if df_full['2ndFlrSF'][row] == 0:
        df_full['Floors'][row] = 1
    else:
        df_full['Floors'][row] = 2

    if df_full['BsmtFinSF1'][row] == 0:
        df_full['Floors'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['Floors'][row] = 1

    if df_full['WoodDeckSF'][row] == 0:
        df_full['WoodDeck'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['WoodDeck'][row] = 1

    if df_full['EnclosedPorch'][row] == 0:
        df_full['EnPorch'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['EnPorch'][row] = 1

    if df_full['OpenPorchSF'][row] == 0:
        df_full['OpPorch'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['OpPorch'][row] = 1

    if df_full['PoolArea'][row] == 0:
        df_full['Pool'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['Pool'][row] = 1

    if df_full['GarageArea'][row] == 0:
        df_full['Garage'][row] = 0
    else:
        df_full['Garage'][row] = 1
```

Comment: The problem isn't that it's doing too much in one go. Each loop takes about 3-4 minutes when it should take 1 second.

Comment: If both computers are running the same versions of python and dependencies, then they should run in similar time depending on relative speed of their processors, etc. However, if you want to make your code faster, you should do one single loop rather than 7 of them, since you are doing 7x more work than you need to.

Comment: @MyNameIsCaleb 1. The resources of the machine can certainly change the running times. 2. Splitting the loop is certainly not a 7x and it is no reason to make the code much slower.

Comment: Doing 7 loops versus 1 loop is literally 7x the amount of operations for that portion of the code. It does not answer the question of why both computers don't run in equal time, but nothing in this code is going to solve that and it isn't really a relevant question for StackOverflow if they are both on equal versions and dependencies.